# peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic can't be reached

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

My code is based on Apple's the CoreBluetooth sample code named "**TemperatureSenor**".
I find a phenomena that if I set peripheral to repeat sending message, then call `peripheral:setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:` , at last `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:` is called.
If I call `peripheral:setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:` to listen messages from peripheral, then set peripheral to send message to central, the central will not call `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:`.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should be sure that whether your characteristic that you use to send message has the notify property which is decided by peripheral.If your characteristic doesn't has notify property but you still call "peripheral:setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:",you will receive unknown error 2. 
If your characteristic  has notify property and you call "peripheral:setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:",the central will call "peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:"